# while converting any file to pdf using Libreoffice it is converting japanese(unicode) characters as brackets

Tags: python, unicode, libreoffice

while converting any file to pdf using Libreoffice it is converting japanese(unicode) characters as brackets.

FOnts are already instlled on server but still it shows brackets after converting.

Comment: It may be related to this bug? https://www.libreoffice.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47668

Comment: It is not related with bug because same version which I am using is converting file correctly but on my client server it is generating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Actuality It was not related to bug.
For resolving the issue I removed the libreoffice

sudo apt-get remove libreoffice-core

sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice

sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get autoremove

After that installed CJK and killed al instances of soffice.bin

sudo apt-get install latex-cjk-all

And refreshed font cache

fc-cache -f -v

This resolved my issue.